# Копирование файлов по локальной сети с аутентификацией

Tags: c#

Есть консольное приложение, в котором нужно копировать файлы по локальной сети как с аутентификацией так и без. Знаю, что без аутентификации можно копировать через `File.Copy`. А вот как правильно будет копировать файлы и папки, если нужна будет windows аутентификация?

Comment: посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17786245/3373603)

Comment: @Ruslan_K а если сеть будет доменной этот вариант подойдет?

Comment: все, спасибо. Нашел еще вариант с учетом [домена](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)